# Why can't I edit Crystal Reports in VS 2019?

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to be able to edit a Crystal Report in VS 2019. I have installed the latest SP26 and still can not get the report to appear. I can modify it in VS 2015 and 2017. I have uninstalled all CR off my machine and only installed SP26. I have ran a repair on VS 2019. Nothing appears to be working. In VS 2015 and VS 2017, I could right click and say "*Open With...*" and it shows "*Crystal Reports Editor (Default)*". In VS 2019, There is no listing of a "Crystal Reports Editor". Any thoughts or ideas would greatly be appreciated.

[Crystal Reports Editor Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1dbC.png)

Comment: Have you installed the Crystal Reports Developer version for Visual Studio since you installed Visual Studio 2019?  While all versions of Visual Studio since 2016 use the same developer version installer, if you installed VS 2019 last and did not reinstall the CR Developer version for VS it will not work until you have done so.

Comment: @R.McMillan I uninstalled all previous Crystal Reports and installed the newest version after VS 2019 and even did a reinstall on CR just now and still not able to edit them. I can't add a new Crystal Reports into the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same behaviour related to SP26 and VS2019 16.4. VS did not want to load the Crystal Report Extension; CR did not even appear inside Help > About Visual Studio > Installed products. 
But I found a solution: Uninstall Crystal Reports Developer Version, uninstall any Visual Studio 2019 Preview version, Install Crystal Reports Developer Version.
- It seems Crystal Report setup gets confused if multiple VS 2019 versions are installed.

Comment: That has done the trick. Thanks so much for finally help figuring out this mystery.